# Exceptions while creating dirs with getDirectoryHandle in specific cases

Tags: javascript, permissions

Update: I raised a [bug report in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1318251). Hopefully this situation can be fixed soon.

I'm trying to create a web app that can modify a directory in order to install mods for a game for the user. It uses [FileSystemDirectoryHandle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryHandle). However, for some reason, using `.getDirectoryHandle("dirname", { create: true })` throws an exception of

```
DOMException: An operation that depends on state cached in an interface object was made but the state had changed since it was read from disk.
```

if I drag the directory into it. If I pick the directory using `window.showDirectoryPicker()`, it doesn't happen.

It also only happens for directories in `.local` and subfolders. As for anything about that directory in particular, it has `drwx------` from `ls -la`. Using the utility `lsd` fails in anything inside of the `.local` directory, but `/usr/bin/ls` works fine, and Nautilus works fine in there too. If it matters, I'm on Ubuntu and using Chromium.

Here's a demo page (needs to be hosted on localhost):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Testing DragN'Drop</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background: #0a2d2e;
        color: #fff;
        font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Drag anywhere!</p>
    <button>Browse.</button>
    <script>
      addEventListener("dragover", (e) => e.preventDefault(), false);
      addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.dataTransfer.items[0].getAsFileSystemHandle().then(handleHandle);
      });
      document.querySelector("button").onclick = async () => {
        const handle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
        handleHandle(handle);
      };
      const handleHandle = (handle) => {
        console.log(handle);
        handle
          .getDirectoryHandle("never", { create: true })
          .then(console.log)
          .catch(console.error);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(I understand that this question *could* fit more on other Stack Exchange sites, but I'm asking here first because I don't know of any yet are that good of a fit.)

Answer (score 1):

2 issues.

1. You need to enable https for [`getAsFileSystemHandle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/getAsFileSystemHandle) to work.
   Follow [these instructions](https://medium.com/webisora/how-to-enable-https-on-live-server-visual-studio-code-5659fbc5542c) for it to work with vscode.
   Assuming you use vscode;

- Create a .crt and .key with openssl >
  `openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout selfsigned.key -out selfsigned.crt`
- Create a settings.json in /.vscode folder

```json
{
    "liveServer.settings.https": {
        "enable": true, //set it true to enable the feature.
        "cert": "X:\\code\\selfsigned.crt", //full path of the certificate
        "key": "X:\\code\\selfsigned.key", //full path of the private key
        "passphrase": "1234"
    }
}
```

2. Function `handleHandle` need to be declated before.

```js
// move this one to the top
const handleHandle = (handle) => {
    console.log(handle);
    handle
        .getDirectoryHandle("never", { create: true })
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
};
addEventListener("dragover", (e) => e.preventDefault(), false);
addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.items[0].getAsFileSystemHandle().then(handleHandle);
});
document.querySelector("button").onclick = async () => {
    const handle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();
    handleHandle(handle);
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding! However, as for your first point, localhost is always marked as secure. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts. And your second point doesn't seem to be relevant.
I feel like this might be a bug with Chromium? Let me know if you think it would be a good idea to report it.

Comment: Oh, disregard my post then.
I'll boot up Ubuntu later today and try.

try and async loop ` e.dataTransfer.items` with exception handling to skip the non-accessible files?